# Do JPA impementor implement javax.persistence.Entity annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have some doubts on who provide the JPA `@Entity annotation`.

I understand that JPA is a standard specification for ORM tools (like hibernate), and these tools implement the JPA specification.

Now in my simple project I have an import statement:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

I was under the impression that since it is "standard" (JPA) specification, there would be **some jars provided by JDK** which would contain this Annotation definition. I searched in various jar's in JDK but there is not any .jar file which has **Entity.class**.

Instead in hibernate there is a jar which has the definition of this `Entity annotation` (jar --> hibearnate-jpa-XX.jar)

So, does it mean in general that these standard specifications aren't part of JDK, and are provided by the specification implementers?

Comment: javax.persistence.Entity is an ANNOTATION provided in the persistence-api.jar Nobody "implements it". JPA is not in the JDK

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I means who "writes" the code of the Entity annotation. So does this mean, the provider who implements these specification provides the code for all these? To me, it appears so. I was under (wrong impression I believe) that the specification's interfaces are provided by the JDK's (from where the imports comes from) and the actual implementation comes from the providers who implement a specification. I want to clear these doubts, and if you can expand a bit, it would be helpful.

Comment: The JPA expert group were supposed to be responsible for providing a spec, an API jar and a TCK. In the case of JPA 2.0 and JPA 2.1 they didn't provide the API jar (due to laziness) and left it to JPA implementations to provide an API jar along with their JPA implementation (and so there are many JPA API jars out there, one for Hibernate, one for EclipseLink, one for DataNucleus ... all nominally the same).

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks so much for the reply,  things are clearer than before. By the way, what is TCK? I googled for this, and got some strange results, like "Third Culture kid!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA specification was written by the JCP, and an "expert group". The expert group was responsible for providing the spec (document), an API jar (the interfaces, annotations defined in the spec), and a TCK (test compatibility kit) used to confirm whether an implementation implements the spec correctly. In the case of JPA the "TCK" is secret, so the general public cannot test a JPA providers compliance (go figure why they did this).

The API jar includes the `@Entity` annotation as well as everything else defined in the spec.

For JPA 1.0 the expert group provided the API jar, [seen here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0/).
For JPA 2.0 and JPA 2.1 the expert group did not provide the API jar due to laziness. Consequently JPA providers like `DataNucleus`, `Hibernate`, `EclipseLink` had to provide their own API jar alongside their JPA implementation. So you should find the `@Entity` annotation in the JPA providers API jar. For example in the [DataNucleus JPA API jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/datanucleus/javax.persistence/2.1.2/).

Comment: Thanks so much for providing the detailed answer, in addition to your comments.  I wish I could double the points to your answer. Thanks a ton!